# Retrieve Github Action metadata of GITHUB_TOKEN through API

Tags: github-actions, github-api

I am trying to make sure we have a secure way to integrate our cloud and Github Actions.

We have multiple Accounts in our cloud to reduce the blast radius if there is an issue. For this we need to make sure we can assume the correct role to deploy to the correct sub-account. We where planning to do a discovery capability made based on the extraction of the metadata of the `GITHUB_TOKEN` generated in runtime.

[image: idea]

Is there a way to obtain the repo name or action that generated the `GITHUB_TOKEN`?